# Can't connect to mongodb when service is running, raspbian

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a problem with mongodb on raspbian (Raspberry Pi 2). When I boot the system, the mongo service is running in the background by default. I can use a shell locally, but I can't connect to mongo from the local network or outside network. But, if I execute `sudo service mongodb stop` and then start mongo with `sudo mongodb` I can connect without a problem.

[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bxJb.jpg)

[Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmWsR.jpg)

I tried to repair mongo, but it did not help.

Everything is working now, only need to chane bind_ip in /etc/mongo.conf to 0.0.0.0
Thank You for help.

Comment: What account are you running the Mongod service under ? Has this account access to the network?

Comment: According to the documentation the service runs using the `mongodb` user account. Can  you connect if you temporarily grant this account sudo privileges?

Comment: I addded mongodb to 'sudo' and 'adm' group, but still can't connect.

Comment: What is the bind_ip value in /etc/mongodb.conf ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Eb1rqe3Z                                                                     

Changing `#nohttpinterface` to false didnt help

Comment: Your bind_ip value is set to `127.0.0.1` and that means mongod on accepts local connections, see my answer for more details

Answer (score 6):

Your mongodb.conf shows you are limiting to connections from local host only as  `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1`. You can either set it to `bind_ip = 0.0.0.0` allowing all network settings, although it is better to limit access to the IP address of your local network interfaces like this:

```
# Listen to local and LAN interfaces.
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,192.168.161.100
```

Comment: perfect. @Daniel Slaby This answer should be accepted